# Open SSL and P12

Tags: iphone

I'm trying to use the service phone gap build and they are asking for a p.12 file. All i seem to have at the moment is a certificate file.

I obtained this file from a mac and and i'm trying to upload from a windows PC.

Does anyone have any guidance on this?

Answer (score 0):

you can create a p12 file by opening you keychain access on mac and select certificates from the left list find you certificat, right click and select export.
I hope this will do the trick :)